# Why do I not need SFINAE here

Tags: c++, c++14

I was trying to do a motivating example for SFINAE, when
I noticed that you don't need that for the following:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
struct Foo
{
    void add(int count, const T& val) // add "count" number of val's
    {
        cout << "count, val" << endl;
    }

    template<typename It>
    void add(It beg, It end) // add items [beg,end)
    {
        cout << "beg, end" << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    int a=1;
    int xx[] = {1,2,3};
    Foo<int> foo;
    foo.add(xx, xx+3);
    foo.add(2, a);
}
```

This compiles, runs, and prints:

> beg, end 
>   count, val

[try it here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b812eb52c80df699)

I do not understand why the second call to `add` is not ambiguous.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Basically:

- Both overloads are viable.
- Both are match without conversion/promotion.
- `add(int count, const T& val)` is preferred as non template.

Comment: did not know non templates were preferred. useful information.

Comment: @sp2danny In that case, you might want to read about [overload resolution rules](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution).